# How to create a list of plabels in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to create a monitor that will record the maximum plabel. I also have the plabel saved as a patches-own variable. How would I create a list of either one of these that contains every patch's variable? Also, once I do that, how would I get the monitor to show this?

I've tried using (list plabel) but it doesn't work. I've also tried `max plabel` to get the monitor to display the maximum plabel, but that also doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

To create lists of something, the `of` primitive is what you want.  In this case,

```
[plabel] of patches
```

will give you a list of the plabels, to which you can then apply the `max` primitive in your monitor

```
max [plabel] of patches
```

If your patches-only variable were, say, `label-value`, then you could use

```
[label-value] of patches
```

to get the list you want.

You could also look at a subset of patches using `with`.  E.g., if the patches have different colors,

```
max [plabel] of patches with [pcolor = red]
```